# Suggestions for MVC strongly typed view with lots of fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering to use the built-in scalffoding MVC capabilities (MVC 4.0 under VS2012) to create a data entry application.

The data entry I should model could contain around 400 diferent fields for each entity row. All fields would be integers except the keys that are YearMonth and WareHouse

I was wondering if someone knows a good way of presenting such kind of data in a MVC view. I can logically group the data of a single entity in let's say 6 independent grids of 7*5, 7*2*17, 3*5, 5*1, 2*5 and 2*2*17} fields respectively (total 371 fields + 2 key fields).

Only required validation is fields are integers. They could be null.

Additionally I don't have any restriction in how the underlyind database tables should look like. I can use a code first approach.

First approach would be to have a single table with 373 columns but maybe it is better to break it up in several tables. Or maybe I should try to normalize the model and make that each logical entity would be mapped to a table with 3 columns and 371 rows?

Any suggestions?

I think it is clear but let me reiterate one concept. When a user creates an entry it should be able to enter the 371 fields no more no less. They could leave the field empty if it wants.

Comment: From a technical stand point, it can be done. Your data types will need to be a nullable int (int?) otherwise they will start off with a default value of 0. From a UI stand point, you must be crazy! 371 text boxes in a single form, are you kidding? Who's going to fill that out.

Comment: It is not that much. It is like filling 38 rows at 10 column width in Excel. As I said are all integers, and probably in the range from 0 to 99999. The key IMO is showing the text boxes in a tabular fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all these fields are a parts of something big, I would create one table in DB. Later it will be easely to work with and faster than searching data in different tables.

As to 371 fields in your form, I think they can logicaly be devided by groups. In that case I would use jQuery to devide process by steps: Step1: show first ten fields; Step2:Hide first fileds and show next ten fields an so on. Technically it can be done by just playing with hide() and show() jQuery methods.

Comment: jQuery hide and show would work with POSTing the whole entity when saving?

Comment: @Eduard I think it should work. Post takes data from all feilds hiden and shown.